# react native state TypeError: One of the sources for assignhas an enumerable key on the prototype chain

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native

I'm having trouble understanding state and setState and can't get my code to work:

constructor:

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      Ingredient : getRandomIngredient(baseArray)
    }
  }
```

button:

```
<Button title="Mix Salad"
                onPress = {()=>this.handleButtonPress()}
        />
```

function:

```
handleButtonPress= () => {
    this.setState(
      this.Ingredient = getRandomIngredient(baseArray)
    )
  }
```

The error occurs once i press the button.
Question a) How do I use state and setState correctly?
Question b) The initial state doesn't persist through the render() function. My Ingredient object remains undefined. That probably isn't intended. What can I do that the Ingredient object retains it's values?

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong syntax

```
this.setState(
  this.Ingredient = getRandomIngredient(baseArray)
)
```

correct :

```
this.setState({ Ingredient : getRandomIngredient(baseArray) })
```

**SetState function take ALWAYS and object parameter**

EDit :
take care about async function, if `getRandomIngredient()` take time to return value so Ingredient will be null

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an object in your `setState`.

```
handleButtonPress = () => {
    this.setState({
        Ingredient: getRandomIngredient(baseArray)
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks! this is probably asking too much, but would you mind explaining why i should a normal function over an arrow in this case? what do you mean by they have different this?

Comment: Whoops - sorry, I put the wrong thing in the answer (arrow functions have a lexical `this`)